# Header won't redirect because the text is too long?

Tags: header

Hey so seeing this title you should be thinking what am I on about ?

Well i'm making a site using php, so when I log in it works and redirects properly, and when I logout it doesn't. UNLESS if I remove a menu link.

The problem IS NOT from the link, because I also tryed putting 7 times the same link, if I only put it 6 times the header() works, if I put 7, it does not redirect. Has anyone already had this problem ? maybe à css problem or something ? I don't use any width for menu bars.

I just don't understand why if I add a menu link it doesn't redirect and if I remove the menu link it redirects and works perfectly (the menu link is NOT the problem)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with stuff, I might of found the problem but I don't understand how to resolve it.

here is when it doesn't work:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['user_username']): ?>
    <?php if ($adminpower > 1): ?>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=admin">Admin</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And it works if it's like this:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['user_username']): ?>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=admin">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which obviously it's good for me because if the user is not at least level 2 (meaning being a level 2 admin) he still get's to see the "admin" menu (even if you get redirected when you click on it because you don't have the level)